# how I can store JTextField input into an arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, swing, browser, jtextfield

I am trying to make a web browser in java sawing and am trying to see how I can store JTextField input into an arraylist which i can then access to show web history and use to iterate back and forward for forward and back navigation buttons please can someone help i am so stuck

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.text.html.*;

public class Browser_main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Quest");

    JTextField user_home_page = new JTextField("");

    String initialURL = "http://www.google.com/";

    final JEditorPane editor_pane_browser;

    ImageIcon url_Icon = new     ImageIcon("/Users/GeorgeBradley/Desktop/url-icon.png");
    JLabel url_label = new JLabel(url_Icon);

    final JTextField txtURL = new JTextField(initialURL, 60);

    ImageIcon search_Icon = new ImageIcon("/Users/GeorgeBradley/Desktop/Search-icon.png");
    JButton browse_button = new JButton("Search", search_Icon);

    ImageIcon refresh_Icon = new ImageIcon("/Users/GeorgeBradley/Desktop/refresh-icon.png");
    JButton refresh_button = new JButton(refresh_Icon);

    ImageIcon forward_Icon = new ImageIcon("/Users/GeorgeBradley/Desktop/Actions-go-next-icon.png");
    JButton forward_button = new JButton(forward_Icon);

    ImageIcon backward_Icon = new ImageIcon("/Users/GeorgeBradley/Desktop/Actions-go-previous-icon.png");
    JButton backward_button = new JButton(backward_Icon);

    ImageIcon home_Icon = new ImageIcon("/Users/GeorgeBradley/Desktop/home-icon.png");
    JButton home_button = new JButton(home_Icon);


    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    panel.add(home_button);
    panel.add(backward_button);
    panel.add(forward_button);
    panel.add(refresh_button);
    panel.add(url_label);
    panel.add(txtURL);
    panel.add(browse_button);

    //making tabbed pane
    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
    ImageIcon tabbed_Icon =new ImageIcon("/Users/GeorgeBradley/Desktop/Hat-icon.png");

    //JComponent panel1 = makeTextField("Panel #1");
    //tabbedPane.addTab("Tab 1");
    //tabbedPane.setMnemonicAt(0, KeyEvent.VK_1);



    try {
        editor_pane_browser = new JEditorPane(initialURL);
        editor_pane_browser.setEditable(false);

        editor_pane_browser.addHyperlinkListener(new HyperlinkListener() {

            public void hyperlinkUpdate(HyperlinkEvent e) {
                if (e.getEventType() == HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED) {
                    JEditorPane pane = (JEditorPane) e.getSource();
                    if (e instanceof HTMLFrameHyperlinkEvent) {
                        HTMLFrameHyperlinkEvent evt = (HTMLFrameHyperlinkEvent) e;
                        HTMLDocument doc = (HTMLDocument) pane.getDocument();
                        doc.processHTMLFrameHyperlinkEvent(evt);
                    } else {
                        try {
                            pane.setPage(e.getURL());
                        } catch (Throwable t) {
                            t.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        home_button.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener(){
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                     try {
                         editor_pane_browser.setPage(initialURL);
                     } catch (IOException ex){
                         ex.printStackTrace();
                     }
                    }
                }
                );

        browse_button.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        try {
                            editor_pane_browser.setPage(txtURL.getText().trim());
                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(txtURL,"INVALID URL");
                        }
                    }
                });

        refresh_button.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener(){
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                        try {
                            editor_pane_browser.setPage(txtURL.getText().trim());
                        } catch (IOException error_refreshing) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(refresh_button, "ERROR REFRESHING PAGE");;
                        }
                    }
                });

        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(editor_pane_browser);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.getContentPane().add(sp, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.setSize(500, 350);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: arraylist and counter should work together. to store it use `list.add(textfield.getText());`

Comment: so all i would do is initialise an array then do list.add(txtURL.getText());

Comment: See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. That’s a lot of code. Not too much for a browser, I know, but too much for a Stack Overflow question. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @GeorgeRichardEdwardBradley yes but if it should contain your urls, it should be called every time you call a new url